# Can MDP or reinforcement learning method be used on an And-Or graph?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning

I want to perform a pathfinding task in a graph using RL, I consider each node of the graph as a state, but there are and/or relations between these states.So I'm wondering if I can still use the traditional MDP or RL methods in that case, and if not how can I improve it, or is there any other way? (Besides AO*)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: States are, in the jargon of McKinsey, MECE - Mutually Exclusive and Comprehensively Exhaustive.  I'm not sure what you mean by "and/or relationship", but if it means the actor can be in two states at once, I suggest you redefine the states.